# Excel blank cells with XSSF POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I'm trying to store dome data to an .xlsx excel file.

The problem is that I can't write blank cells, even if I'm using row.createcell().
I get Null Pointer Excpetion errors, maybe it's because rows aren't initialized.

Is there any way to initialize rows?
 Thanks

Here's the method I've written

```
private static void sendOrderSingle(String account, String symbol,
        String securityID, String securityExchange, double price,
        String side, double orderQty, String ordType)
        throws SessionNotFound, IOException {

    quickfix.fix42.NewOrderSingle order = new quickfix.fix42.NewOrderSingle();

    SessionID sessionId = (SessionID) initiator.getSessions().get(0);

    order.set(new TransactTime(new Date(0)));
    order.set(new HandlInst('1'));
    order.set(new Account(account));
    order.set(new Symbol(symbol));
    order.set(new SecurityID(securityID));
    order.set(new SecurityExchange(securityExchange));
    order.set(new Price(price));
    order.set(new OrdType(OrdType.LIMIT));
    if (side.equals("BUY")) {
        order.set(new Side(Side.BUY));
    } else {
        order.set(new Side(Side.SELL));
    }
    order.set(new OrderQty(orderQty));
    order.set(new OrdType(OrdType.LIMIT));
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("Excel/Data.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFCell cellClOrdIds = null;
    cellClOrdIds = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(18);
    Row row = sheet.getRow((int) cellClOrdIds.getNumericCellValue());
    Cell cell0 = row.getCell(0);
    if (cell0 == null) {
        cell0 = row.createCell(0);
    }
    cell0.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell0.setCellValue(account);
    sheet.getRow(1).getCell(18)
            .setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(cellClOrdIds.toString()) + 1);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Excel/Data.xlsx");
    workbook.write(fos);
    fos.close();
    order.set(new ClOrdID(Integer.parseInt(cellClOrdIds.toString())+""));
    Session.sendToTarget(order, sessionId);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "can't"? What happens if you try?

Comment: Please have a look at this page in the help center on how to create a "Minimal, Complete and Verifiable" example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I'd love to help you but I don't have all your trade-related classes (please **don't** post them) and your problem is not related to them, so you should be able to make an example the tries to write just an empty cell and that fails.

Comment: Could you answer your own question with the solution you found, please? Maybe it will help other people.